# struts 1 radio button grouping

Tags: jsp, struts, radio-button, grouping

Struts 1.x
I have a single row of radio buttons and 2 different items that hold different properties. This creates 2 different groups of input radio buttons. Once with the name="item_t1" and another with name="item_t2".
These are then not grouped together. How can i group them together. I know radio buttons are grouped by name, but in this case, name has a different context.

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="searchResults" property="searchResultsList">
<logic:notEmpty name="item" property="itemId_type1" >
    <bean:define id="itemId_t1" name="item" property="itemId_type1"/>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
        <html:radio property="selectedItemId_t1" value="<%=itemId_t1%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</logic:notEmpty>
<logic:notEmpty name="item" property="itemId_type2" >
    <bean:define id="itemId_t2" name="item" property="itemId_type2"/>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
            <html:radio property="selectedItemId_t2" value="<%=itemId_t2%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</logic:notEmpty>
</logic:iterate>
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say "How can i group them together" do you mean visually? At the moment it looks like you have each radio button on a separate line in a table. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Dont mean visually. I mean as in selection. As you select the button only a single radio button is selected if they are grouped. I want all these buttons in the same 'group.' Right now radio button of selectedItemId_t1 is a different group than selectedItemId_t2. Therefore you can have 2 different radio buttons selected, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts 1.x,  elements with the same property will be grouped. So the reason you have two groups is that you have a set of radio buttons linked to the 'selectedItemId_t1' property and another set linked to the 'selectedItemId_t2' property.

You'll need to link both sets (t1 and t2) to the same property in your form (e.g. a property selectedItemId) and then, if you need to distinguish which is from which set do this by parsing the value. For example, you could set the value to "t1<%=itemId_t2%>" and "t2<%=itemId_t2%>" and in your selectedItemId setter parse the value to take off the first 2 characters (giving you whether they are t1 or t2).

Comment: i was hoping there was a more jsp level way to fix this, but im guessing there isnt. i was hoping to link those elements even tho they have a diferent properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i did find a jsp level way of doing it without changing the Form. I used standard input types. and set the fields as hidden properties. I  set the onClick for the radio button to set the fields respectively.

```
<html:hidden property="itemId_t1" styleId="itemId_t1"/>
<html:hidden property="itemId_t2" styleId="itemId_t2"/>

function setSelectedItemId_t1(item1Id)
{
    getElementById("itemId_t1").value = item1Id
    getElementById("itemId_t2").value = null
}
function setSelectedItemId_t2(item2Id)
{
    getElementById("itemId_t2").value = item2Id;
    getElementById("itemId_t1").value = null
}

<logic:iterate id="item" name="searchResults" property="searchResultsList">
<logic:notEmpty name="item" property="itemId_type1" >
    <bean:define id="itemId_t1" name="item" property="itemId_type1"/>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
        <input type="radio" name="sameItem" value="<%=itemId_t1%>" onclick="setSelectedItemId_t1(value)" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</logic:notEmpty>
<logic:notEmpty name="item" property="itemId_type2" >
    <bean:define id="itemId_t2" name="item" property="itemId_type2"/>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
        <input type="radio" name="sameItem" value="<%=itemId_t2%>" onclick="setSelectedItemId_t2(value)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</logic:notEmpty>
</logic:iterate>
```

This seemed like the best way to do it.